# Store name and value of select option element in different fields in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am using the below code to create a select field . Here the value is getting updated to the ngmodel . I also want to get the name of the option to store in another field 
ie: Value in one field (ID) and name in another field (Selected value) .

Is there any way to achieve this .?

```
( <select name="ORG_ID" #ORG_ID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="siteuses.ORG_ID" class="form-control"
        [class.is-invalid]="!isValid && (siteuses.ORG_ID==''|| siteuses.ORG_ID==null)">
        <option *ngFor="let item of this.sharedService.l_operating_units_s" value="{{item.BU_ID}}">{{item.NAME}}
        </option>
      </select>

)
```

Comment: <select name="ORG_ID" #ORG_ID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="siteuses.ORG_ID" class="form-control"
        [class.is-invalid]="!isValid && (siteuses.ORG_ID==''|| siteuses.ORG_ID==null)">
        <option *ngFor="let item of this.sharedService.l_operating_units_s" value="{{item.BU_ID}}">{{item.NAME}}
        </option>
      </select>

Answer (score 0):

you can use a getter

```
get nameOperating()
{
   operating=this.sharedService.l_operating_units_s
     .find(x=>x.BU_ID==siteuses.ORG_ID);
   return operating?operating.NAME:null;
}
```

or store the full item selected using [ngValue] in the options

```
<select name="ORG_ID" #ORG_ID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="site" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let item of this.sharedService.l_operating_units_s" 
               [ngValue]="item">{{item.NAME}}
        </option>
</select>
<!--just for check-->
{{site.NAME}}{{site.BU_ID}}
```

In "site" you has the full selected, so in site.NAME you has the name, and in site.BU_ID you has the ID